# Finding a substring starting and ending with certain word

Tags: java, groovy, substring

I am trying to extract substrings from each line of a text file by using groovy (or java). I am struggling to find an efficient way to deal with long strings, containing a substring which is of interest to me. Lets say I have the following String:

```
String lineNew = "Error in file C:/Desktop/calc.groovy: assert "A1" == "A2""
```

Now I would like to extract two pieces of information from this string: First, I would like to get the filename, which will always start with C:/ and end with .groovy.
Secondly, I would like to get the error, which will always be the substring which follows "groovy:".

So my problem is basically finding substrings inside a string, which start and end with a specific word. For this reason, methods such as startswith(), matches(), substring() (which works with the position of the words), haven't been working for me.

Has anyone encountered the same problem or knows an efficient method to deal with this kind of problem? Any help is highly appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try capture groups. This is Groovy code:

```
def matches = lineNew =~ /(C:.*?\.groovy): (.*)/
def sourceFile = matches[0][1]     // C:/Desktop/calc.groovy
def errorMessage = matches[0][2]   // assert "A1" == "A2"
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is take the index of "C:/" and ".groovy". so, something like:

```
int start = lineNew.indexOf("C:/");
int end = lineNew.indexOf(".groovy");
String filename = lineNew.substring(start, end);
int errIndex = lineNew.indexOf(whatever marks the end of the error);
String error = lineNew.substring(end, errIndex);
```

I haven't done Java in a bit so I forget whether the substring method is inclusive or what exact index the indexOf method returns, so you'll have to figure that one out, but the general logic should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at pattern matching to solve this.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String lineNew = "Error in file C:/Desktop/calc.groovy: assert \"A1\" == \"A2\"";
    // define two groups, one for file name and second for message
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*(C:.*.groovy):\\s(.*)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(lineNew);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // filename
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2)); // error message
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try with regular expressions - they are quite good with that sort of problem.

Here is a code example I took from [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexMatches {

   public static void main( String args[] ) {
      // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
      String line = "This order was placed for QT3000! OK?";
      String pattern = "(.*)(\\d+)(.*)";

      // Create a Pattern object
      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

      // Now create matcher object.
      Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
      if (m.find( )) {
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2) );
      }else {
         System.out.println("NO MATCH");
      }
   }
}
```

There is a very good Regex matcher [here](https://regex101.com/r/hoMhIN/1/) that also explains what the various elements will match. [Here](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html) is a list of all patterns.

For your first propblem you could use an expression like

`C:.*groovy`

to match the string of the file path.

The second one works like this

```
(?<=groovy:\s).*
```

Note however that using .* like this is a bit dangerous, since it basically matches anything (.) until the next whitespace character (*). Still, if your inputs always look like the one you posted, this will work.